# Ownership/delete'ing the facet in a locale (std::locale)

Tags: c++, boost, locale, facet, boost-date-time

I wrote the following function to get a date/time string using [boost.date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

```
namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;

string
get_date_time_string(bpt::ptime time)
{
  bpt::time_facet * facet(new bpt::time_facet);
  facet->format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");

  stringstream return_value;
  return_value.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), facet));
  return_value << time;

  return return_value.str();
}
```

I had a quick question about the ownership/`delete`'ing of the `facet` object. [std::locale's constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/locale/locale/) is not explicit on the ownership/`delete`'ing of the `facet`. Tried using `shared_ptr`-wrapped and stack allocated versions of `facet` - both of which caused seg-faults. Also, running the above function through valgrind didn't show any leaks(which probably implies that the locale or stream is taking care of `delete`'ing), but I just wanted to be clear that I am doing the right thing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735), a 0 argument passed to the constructor tells the `facet` that the `locale` will handle destruction, and the both constructors of `bpt::time_facet` default to 0 when it isn't supplied.  A non-zero value, though, implies that the programmer must explicitly handle the destruction of the `facet`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. [RTFM](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/locale/facet/), huh?! ;)

Comment: Don't feel to bad, I've asked the same types of questions!

Comment: Wow, I wish they would revisit this part of the std library with the advent C++11..

Comment: @Zac if you think something should be reviewed, become involved with the [process](http://isocpp.org/std).