# C++: Is it ever absolutely necessary to allocate memory manually?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm relatively new to some of the more advanced aspects of C++ programming and I'm having some trouble understanding if it is ever truly necessary to allocate memory in C++ (whether it be through malloc, new, etc.). For example in C, I understand you need to allocate memory to have a dynamically sized array or other tasks. In C++, it seems to me that's not the case, you can just use a std::vector, std::string, or other built in methods which are already dynamically sized by design. I also understand that accessing allocated memory is slower vs the stack.

So given that, are there times when you must allocate memory in C++, and if so, what is an example of one of those times? This of course does not include times when your C++ code must interact with a C program. Let's assume the program is written purely in C++.

EDIT: To try to alleviate confusion, I understand that vectors and other structures are allocating their own memory, but that's something that happens behind the scenes and does not require the programmer to use new, malloc, etc. and it is cleaned up automatically. So what I'm really wondering is, is it ever necessary to perform memory management manually in C++

Comment: You realize that `std::vector` manages a dynamically allocated array (typically on "the heap") behind the scenes, right?

Comment: It reads like you're saying that when a `vector` automatically allocates memory, that doesn't count as "allocating memory".  Is that correct?  Are you asking if it's necessary to explicitly use `new`/`delete`?

Comment: @DrewDormann That's right yeah. I've edited my question to make it clearer in that regard.

Comment: The new rule of thumb is "if you're calling new, you're doing it wrong." (except if you hand the pointer to a unique_ptr.) RAII and the STL for the win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack is of a limited size, some things just won't fit in it reliably. Dynamically allocated memory also has the *dynamic* nature to them, where sometimes you're not sure how many objects or elements in an array you will require until some moment in time of the execution of the program.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c), it does a great job of describing possible use cases for each:

> Heap allocations (dynamically allocated memory) is useful when you want to be more flexible than the above. Frequently, a function gets called to respond to an event (the user clicks the "create box" button). The proper response may require allocating a new object (a new Box object) that should stick around long after the function is exited, so it can't be on the stack. But you don't know how many boxes you would want at the start of the program, so it can't be a static.

To reflect your edit: Indeed it's not really required, or rather, it's typically abstracted away as is the case with `vector` and `string`. You have various containers like `vector` which handle that for you. When you design your own classes, you're encouraged to employ the technique of [Resource Allocation is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (RAII) which abstracts away the typical manual memory management. In fact, in certain cases, especially when dealing with C code, you're encouraged to manage that memory either in a C++ class wrapper employing RAII or with a C++ smart pointer such as those introduced in C++11: [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (which themselves employ RAII).

Answer (score 7):

> For example in C, I understand you need to allocate memory to have a dynamically sized array or other tasks. In C++, it seems to me that's not the case, you can just use a std::vector or other built in methods which are already dynamically sized by design.

`std::vector` isn’t built on magic and fairy dust, though: it allocates memory internally.

You’re right that in C++ [you rarely need to allocate memory *manually*](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/). There are instances where that’s the easiest way though<sup>1</sup>. The point is that C++ makes the manual *deallocation* completely unnecessary because destructors will take care of that.

---

<sup>1</sup> Very, *very* rarely. Most well-written code won’t need this at all. It’s occasionally useful when dealing with lower-level details (for instance when implementing a container).

Answer (score 6):

If your question is, "*Is dynamically allocated memory unnecessary in C++?*" The answer is that it is very necessary, and very important.

If your question is, "*Using modern C++11 classes and features, how frequently will my code require me to manually use '**new**' and '**delete**'*"?

The answer to that is, 'infrequently'. Most of the new and delete calls will be hidden away in containers (***std::vector***, ***std::map***, et al) and smart pointers ( **std::shared_ptr** and **std::unique_ptr**), and through calls to functions like **std::make_shared()**.

Will you on rare occasions need to call 'new' and 'delete' manually? It depends on the type of program you are making, but if they are videogames, I'd say that yes, probably 1% of the time (my experience, but YMMV), you'll need to use manual ***new*** and ***delete*** over **std::make_shared()** and **std::shared_ptr** - though again, it'll depend on the project.

In general, prefer local variables and member variables that are allocated on the stack (ignoring if they allocate dynamic memory internally), next prefer C++11 managed dynamic memory (smart pointers), finally resort to ***new*** and ***delete*** as a last resort if performance requires it (but don't pre-optimize - profile and find the real bottlenecks).

Note, just because you are managing your memory with smart pointers, doesn't mean you should ban all raw pointers from your code - even if all your memory is being managed, there is still very real use for raw pointers unrelated to memory lifetime management.

Answer (score 3):

As you've observed, it is never necessary to use `new` with standard containers (`vector`, `map`, etc.)

When using smart pointers it is always better to use `make_shared` than `new` into a `shared_ptr`; for `unique_ptr` the absence of `make_unique` is a defect ([make_unique and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding)) which should be addressed soon; it's better to copy-paste and use `make_unique` than `new` into `unique_ptr`s yourself, for reasons of clarity and exception safety.

If you're writing your own containers, where possible try to compose standard library facilities (existing containers and smart pointers) so that you don't have to worry about lifetime management.

There is one standard facility where the use of `new` is expected; the templated constructor of `std::locale` taking a `Facet *` by default expects a `Facet *` allocated by `new`, since it will be disposed with `delete static_cast<locale::facet*>(f)` once it is no longer used by `std::locale` instances.  (Note that `std::locale::facet` has a virtual destructor.)  If this makes you uncomfortable you can arrange to manage the lifetime of the facet yourself by passing `1` as the `refs` parameter when constructing the facet: [Ownership/delete'ing the facet in a locale (std::locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330459/ownership-deleteing-the-facet-in-a-locale-stdlocale).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to yourself. I have always done something like the below

```
void foo(MyStruct&v) { v.bar=1234 }
vector<MyStruct> v;
v.push_back(...);
```

Essentially single values are on the stack while a collection is on the stack but puts everything in a heap. I don't ever use the new keyword or pointers in the majority of my apps.

Comment: "I have always", "I don't ever use". This answer seems more subjective than it needs to be. 2 out of 3 phrases are subjective (leaving "You don't need to yourself"). Would you mind improving it with some more *real* information?